# Asymmetric "enlarge x limits" in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to specify different "enlarge x limits" for the lower and upper axis extrema. Something like `enlarge x limits={{value=0.2,upper}, {value=0.4,lower}}` does not work however. Any ideas? Using xmin and xmax to modify the range first is not an option as I use "symbolic x coords".

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,ymin=0,symbolic x coords={a,b,c}, enlarge x limits=true, xtick=data, legend pos=south east]
\addplot coordinates { (a,10) (b,15) (c,20) };
\addlegendentry{legend}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here I want to make room at lower side to show the bar properly and add more whitespace at the upper side to make room for the legend (I prefer to keep the legend inside the plot).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. I also helps to test that the solution indeed does work.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74497/pgfplots-axis-enlargelimits
I found the helpful response given by @zeroth to this question under this link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PGFPlots uses the same value for both upper and lower limit in `enlarge * limits`; the use-case of different values is unsupported (sorry). You may need to consider a different solution.

Comment: This seems to be possible by now using the `upper` and `lower` keys to `enlargelimits` or `enlarge * limits` (found in the manual of version 1.16 on page 329, section 4.14.1).

Comment: @AlexPovel: How? OP writes that exactly that does not work. You can specify one, but not both.

Comment: @Christian Feuersänger: Just to be sure - it is still not possible!? I wanted to have used it in my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618105/8650

Answer (score 0):

Without a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) I am not sure I fully understand the problem. But, it appears that using `xmax` to specify the upper limit even with `symbolic x coords` seems to work fine.  Here I specified `xmax=i`, and did not specify `xmin`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=i,symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}]
    \addplot+[smooth] coordinates { (a,42) (b,50) (c,80) (f,60) (g,62) (i,90)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I have misunderstood your question, please provide a specific compilable example.

Comment: The example is representative enough, but the problem is that you cannot extend the whitespace using `xmax`, only limit it to the last datapoint. I need to extend the whitespace both at the upper and lower end, but in different proportions.