# pgfplots axis enlargelimits

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image with axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38632/image-with-axis)

I want to place an image against the edge of an axis frame, but because of the (unknown to me) value of the enlarged limits, I can't find the coordinates both where to place it and what the height should be.

This is what I'm talking about:

[image: Plot]

And my code looks something like.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=colora] file {data.dat};
\node[anchor=base east] at (axis cs:0,0) {\includegraphics[height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{myimage.png}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

What you are looking for is the `enlargelimits=false` which should always be used when inserting graphics. Also know that you should explicitly add limits for your plot! `pgfplots` can not read that from the image. Thus always set:

```
xmin
xmax
ymin
ymax
```

when using graphics.

However, I would recommend you to look into the `\addplot graphics` command which can basically do what you want. And is a lot easier to maintain for sizes of the graphics, etc.

Take the example in the manual and do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[small, enlargelimits=false,axis on top]
    \addplot graphics [xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3] {external1};
    % Add a second graph on top of the graphics (be sure to have
    % graphics first!
    \addplot coordinates { (1,1) (1,2) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will look like this:

[image]

If you instead wish to have it clammed at the right side, just do the same, but specify the extra filling in the axis environment. This you do by using `enlarge x limits={abs value=<extra x space>,lower}`. `lower` can also be `upper` if needed.

```
\begin{axis}[small,enlargelimits=false,
    enlarge x limits={abs value=2,lower},axis on top]
  \addplot graphics [xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3] {external1};
  \addplot coordinates { (-4,1) (1,2) };
  \addplot coordinates { (1,1) (1.25,2.5) };
\end{axis}
```

This will be:

[image]

The last thing is that if you want it in between the sides. Then simply specify the limits in the `axis` environment explicitly.

As Jake mentioned the `axis equal image` key can be used to **keep aspect ratio**. It conserves the limits (unlike `axis equal`)

Try and insert `axis equal image` and you will get:

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Maybe it's also a good idea to mention the `axis equal image` key, which ensures that the image is not squashed.

Comment: @Jake added, however, they have some troubles retaining the axis limits when adding that key. :) For obvious reasons...

Comment: Thanks! Though I actually meant `axis equal image`, which is slightly different from `axis equal=true` in that the unit vectors in x and y direction do not have to be the same.

Comment: @Jake ah yes of course (exactly what solves the problem of axis limits), I read your comment much too fast! :)