# Axis scaling issue with external graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was referring to the following posts

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PuiQ.jpg): [Image with axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38632/image-with-axis), [2]: [pgfplots axis enlargelimits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74497/pgfplots-axis-enlargelimits?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I was trying to fit my image in a defined axis. Unfortunately, the image is not scaling correctly(aspect ratio always changes). The image is as below,(i take it as a pdf for my tikz picture)

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%small, 
    axis equal image,
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top,
    axis equal=false
    ]
    \addplot graphics [xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=10,ymax=2] {fig1.pdf};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the not so MWE version(if needed)

```
%\documentclass{standalone}
%
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%
%\begin{document}
%  \begin{tikzpicture}
%    \begin{axis}[
%        axis on top,% ----
%        width=5cm,
%        scale only axis,
%        enlargelimits=false,
%        xmin=0,xmax=10,
%        xlabel={Length($mm$)},
%        xtick={0,2,4,6,8,10},
%        xticklabels={0,2,4,6,8,10},
%           scaled ticks=false,
%           axis equal image,   
%        ymin=0,ymax=2,
%        ylabel={Length($mm$)},
%        ytick={0.1,0.5 ,1,1.5,2},
%        yticklabels={0.1,0.5 ,1,1.5,2},
%        axis equal=false,
%        axis equal image,
%        ]
%
%      \addplot[thick,blue] graphics[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=10,ymax=2] {fig1.pdf};
%    \end{axis}
%  \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{document}
```

Comment: We need code we can use to reproduce the problem. Since only you have `fig1.pdf`, nobody but you can compile the code to diagnose or troubleshoot.

Comment: I copied your image and it worked fine.  You do realize that `axis equal image` and `axis equal=false` cancel, and neither is needed.  If you want a specific aspect ratio, set the width and height using `scale axis only`.

Comment: BTW, the default size of this image is about 97 by 45 inches.  It still works but the tick labels are too small to be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following preserves the original aspect ratio, but scales it down to a given width (4in).  You will need to change the pathname for your system.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=4in]{images/7PuiQ}}%

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%small, 
    scale only axis, width={\wd0}, height={\ht0},
    enlargelimits=false,% not needed
    axis on top,
    ]
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=10,ymax=2] {images/7PuiQ};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]