# Extend the axes while keeping the graph within the coordinate system

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I want to extend the y-axis so that the value of the maximum on the graph isn't at tip of the y-axis arrow. (I also want to extend the x-axis for the same reason). See an example below:
[image: Picture]
What I want should look something like this (found in: https://tikz.dev/dv-axes)
[image: Another pic]

I would also like to include ticks as in this picture to my example.

Thank you! (Sorry for big pictures, I do not know how to scale them here)

Codes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=1in,top=1.2in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-5,    xmax=5,
ymin=-0.5,    ymax=5,
ticks=none,
axis y line=middle,
axis x line=middle,
axis line style=thick,
ytick pos=upper,
xlabel=$(1)$,   ylabel=$(2)$,
x label style={anchor=west},
y label style={anchor=south},
]
\addplot [
    ultra thick,
    domain=-10:10, 
    color=black!50!green,
    smooth
    ]
    {0.3333333*x^2};
%\addlegendentry{\(\frac{1}{3}x^2\)}

\addplot [
    ultra thick,
    domain=-10:10, 
    color=black!20!blue,
    smooth
    ]
    {x^2};
%\addlegendentry{\(x^2\)}

\addplot [
    ultra thick,
    domain=-10:10, 
    color=black!10!red,
    smooth
    ]
    {3*x^2};
%\addlegendentry{\(3x^2\)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=8cm, height=10cm,
xmin=-20, xmax=20,
ymin=0, ymax=40,
axis lines=middle, axis line style=thick,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$f(x)$,
xlabel style={anchor=west}, ylabel style={anchor=south},
enlarge x limits={abs=2}, enlarge y limits=0.1,
]
\clip (-20,0) rectangle (20,40);
\addplot[
red!90!black, ultra thick,
domain=-20:20, 
smooth
] {0.5*x^2};
\addplot[
green!50!black, ultra thick,
domain=-20:20, 
smooth,
] {0.1*x^2};
\addplot[
blue!80!black, ultra thick,
domain=-20:20, 
smooth
] {0.05*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with three parabolas]

You can also use the option `axis line style={shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt}` to simply draw the axis lines longer. This has some limitations - no ticks in this extension, no grid, and manual adjustment of e.g. labels are needed.

Comment: Thanks! I am curious to learn, what if you want the line under x-axis to be bit smaller, while keeping the axis above the x-axis? I was thinking changing your `enlarge y limits` into like `enlarge y limits={value=0.1,upper}`, then what should I write to get one under x-axis with a smaller distance?

Comment: That is not supported - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30437/asymmetric-enlarge-x-limits-in-pgfplots . You could enlarge the upper limit and then negative shorten the lower of the axis line. `enlarge y limits={value=0.1, upper}, y axis line style={shorten <=-5pt}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `restrict y to domain=0:5`  and `axis line style={-to}`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-5,    xmax=5,
ymin=-0.5,    ymax=6,
ticks=none,
axis y line=middle,
axis x line=middle,
axis line style={-to},
restrict y to domain=0:5,
axis line style=thick,
ytick pos=upper,
xlabel=$(1)$,   ylabel=$(2)$,
x label style={anchor=west},
y label style={anchor=south},
]
\addplot [
ultra thick,
domain=-5:5, 
color=black!50!green,
smooth,
samples=750,
]
{x^2/3};
%\addlegendentry{\(\frac{1}{3}x^2\)}

\addplot [
ultra thick,
domain=-5:5, 
color=black!20!blue,
smooth,
samples=500,
]
{x^2};
%\addlegendentry{\(x^2\)}

\addplot [
ultra thick,
domain=-5:5, 
color=black!10!red,
smooth,
samples=1100,
]
{3*x^2};
%\addlegendentry{\(3x^2\)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: With `restrict y to domain`, the plots will end at different heights (the last sampled point within this domain). `axis line style={-to}` changes the arrow tip!?

Comment: @hpekristiansen `axis line style={-to}` will change the arrow tip. Regarding `restrict y to domain`, that's true, that's why I added some many samples points. With `samples at = {}` you can modify the samples points

Comment: Yes, but why are you changing the arrow tip?

Comment: because I thought the OP wanted that